# Grouping of Wildcard Imports

Tags: kotlin

I'm pretty sure what I want doesn't exist, but I wanted to ask anyway just to make sure.

I have to import a fairly large amount of classes from multiple packages. Many of those classes inside those packages would be ambiguous if I just imported them via wildcard import. Additionally I would really like to avoid having to do those imports one by one, renaming them individually.

So what I am essentially looking for is something like this:

```
import PackageA.* as MyA
import PackageB.* as MyB

val aFoo = MyA.FooClass()
val bFoo = MyB.FooClass()
```